# Solve Equation - Eternal Running

Tags: equation-solving

I'm new in mathematica and trying to solve this equation in function of t.

```
1/2 * Sqrt[1 + 4 * Exp^(-2*k*t) * (Exp^(k*t) + Cosh[2*t]) Sinh[t]^2 - 
Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[E^(-4*k*t) (-1 + E^(k*t) + Cosh[2*t])^2*Sinh[2*t]^2]]
```

I use the command Solve,

```
Solve [1/2 * Sqrt[1 + 4 * Exp^(-2*k*t) * (Exp^(k*t) + Cosh[2*t]) Sinh[t]^2 - 
       Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[E^(-4*k*t) (-1 + E^(k*t) + Cosh[2*t])^2*Sinh[2*t]^2]] == 1, t]
```

but mathematica stay running until full my PC memory and restart.

How can I solve this equation in function of t?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not proper Mathematica code. For instance, `Exp^(-2*k*t)` needs to be typed as `Exp[-2*k*t]` and so on.

Comment: If you use either E^(expr) or Exp[expr] then Reduce quickly responds that it has no method to solve this. If you can assign a numeric value to k then the numeric solvers might be able to find solutions.